# Could ASP.NET Web Api be bad for SEO?

Tags: seo, asp.net-web-api

Will Web API based website suffer SEO problems?

Given that all content of a page is being pulled by javascript... 
will search engine crawlers be able to get the page content?

I heard that crawlers do not always support javascript or perform javascript when crawling on a page.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Web API that is bad for SEO, it's choosing an architecture where you use a web browser to navigate to empty HTML pages and then use JS to pull in the data.  ASP.NET Web API does not have to be used that way.
You can't blame a hammer for building a bad house.

Comment: interesting... can you elaborate on that?
the alternative as i see it is to build some sort of a web api repository... right?
that actually makes more sense but it seems abit weird to use an unnecessary middleman.. seem right only in specific situations, but not for the majority of websites...

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

Will ALL search engine crawlers be able to get the page content, I do not know.

Do the search engine crawlers that *matter* get the page content, yes.

Google and Bing combined own the search market, both can index content pulled in by javascript (and probably others as well).

[Robert Scavilla](http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/#!searchbot_differences_for_indexing_ajax_content) on how content is indexed.

[Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-can-now-execute-ajax-javascript-for-indexing-99518) on google executing javascript for indexing.